# NUXT router links with sub-links in a menu

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

I have more or less used this to render out all the links that are in the router that NUXT builds from the pages and sub-directories.

```
<template>
<nav>
  <nuxt-link :class="{ active: route.path === $router.currentRoute.path }"
              v-for="route in $router.options.routes" 
              :key="route.path" 
              :to="route.path">{{ route.name }}
  </nuxt-link>
</nav>
```

My issue is that I have a page structure like:

```
Link
Link
Link 
    Subdirectory
        Link
        Link
```

When I render the routes it gives me a flat map of the links labeled like this:

```
Link Link Link Subdirectory-Link Subdirectory-Link
```

Which isn't very useful. I couldn't find a standard way to do this in NUXT.

The end goal is to build a sidebar with the full map of links, with collapsible sections. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a Nuxt problem. You could use any tutorial on how to template this. Generally looping through all links and then using a conditional to check if it is a level 1 link oder level 2 link